# Empty and null validation for data in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate empty and null date validation , if date is empty to have current date as valid from date.

for example:-

```
var d = null;

d = new Date(d);

document.write(d);

var current = new Date();



 if(d==null || d=='')
    {
    document.write("invalid date set current date")
    document.write(current);

}
```

Can you please suggest on this.
Thanks

Comment: if(d) is sufficient, as it will check if it is not empty nor null

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to create a date before checking if `d` is `null`? Try this:

```
var d = null; // I suppose this will be taken from some kind of input

var current = new Date();

if(d !== null || d !== ''){
    var date = new Date(d);
    var dateTs = date / 1;
    var currentTs = current / 1;

    if(dateTs > currentTs){
        document.write("invalid date set current date");
        document.write(current);
    } else {
        document.write(date);
    }
} else {
    document.write("invalid date set current date");
    document.write(current);
}
```

Comment: I have to check two condition 1.>date cannot be older than current date and  null (that we already checked) that's why create date object first.

Comment: You haven't mention that in question

Comment: I've updated my answer. I reversed the condition. If `d` can be converted to `Date` then check if the date is older. In case of `d` cannot be converted to `Date` or is too big then set to current date

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to check null values. This can be reused within the application.

```
        //A function to check null and empty values
        function isEmpty(value) {
            if (typeof value === "undefined" || value === null || value === "null" || value === "") {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var d = null;
        d = new Date(d);
        document.write(d);
        var current = new Date();

        if(isEmpty(d)){
            var current = new Date();
            document.write("invalid date set current date");
            document.write(current);
        } else {
            var date = new Date(d);
            document.write(date);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just check by following code

```
if(typeof d == "undefined" || !d)
{
   console.log("d is not defined");
}
```